# Evaluating an expression of type shapeless.Witness.Aux[T] in a macro fails

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, shapeless, scala-2.11

I'm trying to evaluate an implicit parameter of type `shapeless.Witness.Aux[T]` in a macro in order to use the value of the singleton type T. This is a minimal example:

```
import shapeless.Witness
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

object Macro {
  def foo[N](implicit aux: Witness.Aux[N]): Unit = macro fooImpl[N]

  def fooImpl[N: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)
                               (aux: c.Expr[Witness.Aux[N]]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._

    val typechecked = aux.tree
    println("Typechecked tree:")
    println(show(typechecked))

    val untypechecked = c.untypecheck(typechecked)
    println("Untypechecked tree:")
    println(show(untypechecked))

    def eval = c.eval(c.Expr(untypechecked))
    val w = scala.util.Try(eval).getOrElse(eval)
    // now use w.value
    c.Expr[Unit](q"()")
  }
}
```

But compiling this

```
val w = shapeless.Witness(true)
Macro.foo[w.T]
```

fails with the following error:

```
[error] overriding value value in trait Witness of type fresh$macro$2.this.T;
[error] value value has incompatible type
```

The output of `println(show(typechecked))` is:

```
{
  final class fresh$macro$2 extends AnyRef with shapeless.Witness {
    def <init>(): fresh$macro$2 = {
      fresh$macro$2.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    type T = Boolean(true);
    private[this] val value: Boolean(true) = true;
    <stable> <accessor> def value: Boolean(true) = true
  };
  new fresh$macro$2()
}
```

The output of `println(show(untypechecked))` is:

```
{
  final class fresh$macro$2 extends AnyRef with _root_.shapeless.Witness {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    type T = Boolean(true);
    private[this] val value: Boolean(true) = true;
    <stable> <accessor> def value: Boolean = true
  };
  new fresh$macro$2()
}
```

I seems to me that problem is that in the untypechecked tree the `value` method has type `Boolean` while the `value` field has type `Boolean(true)` and the compiler needs both types to be the same.

Any ideas how to work around this? Is this even supported to evaluate a macro in a macro?

BTW: This project https://github.com/fthomas/scala-macro contains is a minimal project for reproducing this.

Comment: Am I right to guess that what you're trying to do here is smuggle a compile time _value_ into a macro implementation so that it can be used in a compile time computation?

Comment: @MilesSabin That sounds about right. This came up in the context of the [refined](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) library, where I want this `refineLit[MatchesRegex[shapeless.Witness.\`"[0-9]+"\`.T], String]("123")` to check at compile time that the string "123" matches the regex "[0-9]+".

Comment: Gotcha.`Witness` is really intended for mapping singleton types to _runtime_ values. I think you would probably be better off working directly with your type argument `N` and its type tag and then reusing the logic of `Witness` internally. A fairly straightforward way of doing that would be factoring the bulk of the `Witness` macro into a trait which could be mixed in by your own macro.

Comment: Thanks @MilesSabin for your answer, although that was not the one I was hoping for. :-) It seems that I need to dive deep into macro land. What complicates the matter a little bit is that there is a runtime equivalent of `refineLit` (called `refine`) that is based on the same validation mechanism and for which `Witness` works perfectly.

Comment: If you need a runtime version as well then that might change things.I suspect that your problem above is that untypechecking followed by retypechecking is guaranteed to be the identity. Are you able to eval the tree in its typechecked form?

Also, bear in mind that eval-ing arbitrary code at compile time can be ... risky ;-)

Comment: @MilesSabin I'll take the risks :-) I'm trying to push the idea of compile-time validations as far as I can get it. Eval-ing a typechecked tree is not supported and fails with `scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective toolbox has failed: cannot operate on trees that are already typed`. Explicitly retypechecking the tree with `c.typecheck(untypechecked)` gives me again a tree where the the `value` field has type `Boolean(true)` and the `value` method has type `Boolean`. Apart from that it is identical to the original `aux.tree`.

Comment: OK, rather than using `eval` on the whole `Witness`, can you navigate through the tree and pull out the subtree corresponding to the RHS of val/def definition? You could then use that as a tree or eval it on it's own (which I would expect to work correctly).

Comment: @MilesSabin The actual parameter that my macro takes can contain a complex combination of `Witness` expressions. E.g. `MatchesRegex[Witness.\`"[0-9]+"\`.T] Or Equal[Witness.\`"abc"\`.T]]` would be a predicate I'd like to support. I'm not sure how navigating and pulling out subtrees would help me here. Maybe I could make a weaker version of `Witness` where `value` has a less precise type than `T`. Maybe something like `trait WeakWitness { type T; val value: AnyVal }` could work. Or if `value` would have the non-singleton type of `T` that should work too.

Comment: @MilesSabin I just tried the `WeakWitness` idea in my shapeless fork. And it works! I can eval a `WeakWitness` in a macro and use `value` there (`value` has type `Boolean`, while `T` is `Boolean(true)`. I guess I should continue the discussion in a shapeless PR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem vanished with shapeless 2.2.2 due to the changes in https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/pull/410.